# Getting Date Time in Unix Time as Byte Array which size is 4 bytes with Java

Tags: java, date, arrays, unix-timestamp

How Can I get the date time in unix time as byte array which should fill 4 bytes space in Java?

Something like that:

```
byte[] productionDate = new byte[] { (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x34,
                    (byte) 0x94, 0x54 };
```

Comment: What's wrong with just using `System.currentTimeMillis()`? It's a `long`, but I don't see how that's less useful than a byte array.

Comment: I need to save it as byte array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First: [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is a number of **seconds** since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC. Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns **milliseconds** since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 UTC. So you will have to divide by 1000 to get Unix time:

```
int unixTime = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
```

Then you'll have to get the four bytes in the `int` out. You can do that with the [bit shift operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) `>>` (shift right). I'll assume you want them in [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order:

```
byte[] productionDate = new byte[]{
        (byte) (unixTime >> 24),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 16),
        (byte) (unixTime >> 8),
        (byte) unixTime

};
```

Comment: Tip, though not more efficient: `... = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(unixTime).array();`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to do the byte manipulation.

```
int dateInSec = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(dateInSec).array();
```

You may wish to set the byte order to little endian as the default is big endian.

To decode it you can do

```
int dateInSec = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
```

Comment: It's shorter, but a lot more overhead than my solution, to allocate a `ByteBuffer` just for this...

Comment: @Jesper true, although with escape analysis in Java 8 the ByteBuffer can be allocated on the stack which is not so expensive.