# Convert Time since Epoch to HEX or Byte Array

Tags: go

How can I convert the time since epoch to Hex in Go?

It should look like this: 5E839BAB

See: https://www.epochconverter.com/hex

EDIT: I was not able to find anything similar asked already. My Plan was to get the current time in Unix (Epoch) -> convert it to a Byte Array and then use hex.EncodeToString() to get it as hex

Comment: It's better to include the relevant information to the original question. If the obvious answer isn't what you want, add that. [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the epoch of time value using `t.Unix()`:

```
t:=time.Now()
fmt.Sprintf("%X",t.Unix())
```

To get this as a byte array:

```
import "encoding/binary"
...
out:=make([]byte,4)
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(out,uint32(t.Unix()))
```

Or, use BigEndian.

Comment: Thanks, i knew that already though. I need this as a 4 byte long Byte Array though (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273498/getting-date-time-in-unix-time-as-byte-array-which-size-is-4-bytes-with-java)

Comment: @NecronomiconCoding Added that to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my answer. Just replace int32 with uint32 :)